# Load React16 Build Into another app with RequireJS

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, amd

I built a small React application that ultimately will be in a section on a page with other small apps. The way the system is architected requires that each app be a require module that exports an init function that when called will render the app into a div by id. I have already tweaked my React build so that I have a single js file. Now I'm trying to figure out if I can make this final build be somehow loadable with requirejs. I have found a lot of information about using requirejs as part of the build but I would rather be able to stay with the create-react-app way and maybe somehow add in the ability to do the output in an AMD way. I know this must seem silly but I can't otherwise get around the AMD architecture of this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by tweaking the configuration of `webpack.config.js` file, you need to check out webpack's [`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output#outputlibrary) options (`library`, `libraryExport`, and `libraryTarget`):
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output#module-definition-systems

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    library: 'MyReactAppLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'amd'
  }
}
```